# Dealing with .csv files: Error: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, indexing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4DeE.jpg)Python Machine Learning dealing with .csv files: Error: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('EURGBP.csv')
df.columns = [['date', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume']]
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date,format='%d.%m.%Y  %H:%M:%S.%f')
df = df.set_index(df.date)
print(df.head())
```

`Error: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`

Comment: Hi to everyone, I download a currency trend in CSV file frame from dukascopy.com but can't deal with. I will be very thankful if you help me find my mistake

Comment: how your CSV file look like, headers and on raw data could help  to understand data format. please add it to your question as sample input data

Comment: thank you for your first advice. I upload an image from the table in CSV file. is it clear?  Is it obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is you pass nested list to columns names, so created `'broken'` one level `MultiIndex`, need remove outer `[]`:

```
df.columns = ['date', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume']
```